# R - Replace pattern in colnames in multiple dataframes

Tags: r

I found a few threads on this topic, but no answer to my specific problem. I have multiple dataframes and a vector consisting of the names of these dataframes. I'm using for loops performing the same operation to all of them, for example renaming columns:

```
for (i in import_names_vector) {
assign(i, rename(get(i), x = var1, y = var2, z = var3))
}
```

In a few other columns I want to replace a pattern in the column names. It was easy to come up with a code for a single data frame using gsub:

```
colnames(df) <- gsub("_01", "1", colnames(df))
```

However, I fail to include this statement into a for loop. I tried various combinations of something like this - gettin different error messages:

```
for (i in import_names_vector) {
colnames(i) <- gsub("_01", "1", colnames(get(i)))
}
```

The closest I got was the following, but this converts my dataframes into vectors consisting of the column names only:

```
for (i in import_names_vector) {
assign(i, gsub("_01", "1", colnames(get(i))))
}
```

The pattern replacement works, though. I have the feeling that I am very closy, but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this :

```
result <- lapply(mget(import_names_vector), function(x) 
                 setNames(x, gsub("_01", "1", colnames(x))))
```

Now to get these changed information in your individual dataframes use `list2env`.

```
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Similar to your attempt you can do :

```
for (i in import_names_vector) {
  assign(i, setNames(get(i), gsub("_01", "1", colnames(get(i)))))
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I would have preferred to keep my dataframes separate, not converting them to a list. Does your answer mean, this can't be done in a for loop?

Comment: No I don't mean that. It is recommended to keep data in list when you want to perform same operations in them. I have updated the answer to use `for` loop and both the answers change your original dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation. Now I see what I did wrong in the for loop - and I know how to handle multiple dataframes in the future. Thanks also for pointing me to the list2env function - very handy. I learned a lot! :)